# Is there a way to get Chai working with asynchronous Mocha tests?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js

I'm running some asynchronous tests in Mocha using the Browser Runner and I'm trying to use Chai's expect style assertions:

```
window.expect = chai.expect;
describe('my test', function() {
  it('should do something', function (done) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      expect(true).to.equal(false);
    }, 100);
  }
}
```

This doesn't give me the normal failed assertion message, instead I get:

```
Error: the string "Uncaught AssertionError: expected true to equal false" was thrown, throw an Error :)
    at Runner.fail (http://localhost:8000/tests/integration/mocha/vendor/mocha.js:3475:11)
    at Runner.uncaught (http://localhost:8000/tests/integration/mocha/vendor/mocha.js:3748:8)
    at uncaught (http://localhost:8000/tests/integration/mocha/vendor/mocha.js:3778:10)
```

So it's obviously catching the error, it's just not displaying it correctly. Any ideas how to do this? I guess I could just call "done" with an error object but then I lose all the elegance of something like Chai and it becomes very clunky...

Comment: The problem is with browser-side mocha.  See https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/pull/278 for information about this.

Comment: As of 2020, you should take a look at the `chai-as-promised` plugin...

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Your asynchronous test generates an exception, on failed `expect()`ations, that cannot be captured by `it()` because the exception is thrown outside of `it()`'s scope.

The captured exception that you see displayed is captured using `process.on('uncaughtException')` under node or using `window.onerror()` in the browser.

To fix this issue, you need to capture the exception within the asynchronous function called by `setTimeout()` in order to call `done()` with the exception as the first parameter. You also need to call `done()` with no parameter to indicate success, otherwise mocha would report a timeout error because your test function would never have signaled that it was done:

```
window.expect = chai.expect;

describe( 'my test', function() {
  it( 'should do something', function ( done ) {
    // done() is provided by it() to indicate asynchronous completion
    // call done() with no parameter to indicate that it() is done() and successful
    // or with an error to indicate that it() failed
    setTimeout( function () {
      // Called from the event loop, not it()
      // So only the event loop could capture uncaught exceptions from here
      try {
        expect( true ).to.equal( false );
        done(); // success: call done with no parameter to indicate that it() is done()
      } catch( e ) {
        done( e ); // failure: call done with an error Object to indicate that it() failed
      }
    }, 100 );
    // returns immediately after setting timeout
    // so it() can no longer catch exception happening asynchronously
  }
}
```

Doing so on all your test cases is annoying and not DRY so you might want to provide a function to do this for you. Let's call this function `check()`:

```
function check( done, f ) {
  try {
    f();
    done();
  } catch( e ) {
    done( e );
  }
}
```

With `check()` you can now rewrite your asynchronous tests as follows:

```
window.expect = chai.expect;

describe( 'my test', function() {
  it( 'should do something', function( done ) {
    setTimeout( function () {
      check( done, function() {
        expect( true ).to.equal( false );
      } );
    }, 100 );
  }
}
```

Comment: I just deleted my previous comment after I realised the bit I was complaining about (setTimeout) was actually from my question. Sorry!!

Comment: The above answer seems wrong. A failed expectation will throw immediately and stop the test with a meaningful error, there is no need for a complicated try/catch. I just tested it right now with a browser test.

Comment: It may have been fixed in a later version, the answer pertains to the very real issue exposed in the question, over two years ago. Have you tried to run the answer test code? Which version of Mocha and Chai are you using?

Comment: I was struggling with this issue and found this blog post extremely helpful: http://staxmanade.com/2015/11/testing-asyncronous-code-with-mochajs-and-es7-async-await/

Comment: @RichardForrester, extremely helpful post. Thanks! To get this checking working with Promises incredibly simplifies the code. But it has to be with promises (not any async function).

Comment: Just want to chime in for posterity that this exact problem happens with the Vue nexttick() (which is a wrapper for promise) and can be handled the same way.

Comment: Hello @Jean Vincent, what do you mean by "exception thrown outside of it()" scope? How can this be solved with promises?

Answer (score 21):

Here are my passing tests for ES6/ES2015 promises and ES7/ES2016 async/await. Hope this provides a nice updated answer for anyone researching this topic:

```
import { expect } from 'chai'

describe('Mocha', () => {
  it('works synchronously', () => {
    expect(true).to.equal(true)
  })

  it('works ansyncronously', done => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      expect(true).to.equal(true)
      done()
    }, 4)
  })

  it('throws errors synchronously', () => {
    return true
    throw new Error('it works')
  })

  it('throws errors ansyncronously', done => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      return done()
      done(new Error('it works'))
    }, 4)
  })

  it('uses promises', () => {
    var testPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('Hello')
      }, 4)
    })

    testPromise.then(result => {
      expect(result).to.equal('Hello')
    }, reason => {
      throw new Error(reason)
    })
  })

  it('uses es7 async/await', async (done) => {
    const testPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('Hello')
      }, 4)
    })

    try {
      const result = await testPromise
      expect(result).to.equal('Hello')
      done()
    } catch(err) {
      done(err)
    }
  })

  /*
  *  Higher-order function for use with async/await (last test)
  */
  const mochaAsync = fn => {
    return async (done) => {
      try {
        await fn()
        done()
      } catch (err) {
        done(err)
      }
    }
  }

  it('uses a higher order function wrap around async', mochaAsync(async () => {
    const testPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('Hello')
      }, 4)
    })

    expect(await testPromise).to.equal('Hello')
  }))
})
```

Comment: @Pedro R. I changed to remove done from promise test. As you pointed out, it's not needed.

Answer (score 13):

If you like promised, try [Chai as Promised](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised) + [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), which allow something like this:

```
doSomethingAsync().should.eventually.equal("foo").notify(done);
```

Answer (score 2):

I asked the same thing in the Mocha mailing list. They basically told me this : to write asynchronous test with Mocha and Chai :

- always start the test with `if (err) done(err);`
- always end the test with `done()`.

It solved my problem, and didn't change a single line of my code in-between (Chai expectations amongst other). The `setTimout` is not the way to do async tests.

Here's the [link to the discussion in the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mochajs/4tDByBROM1Y%5B1-25%5D).

Comment: The discussion you linked to is about server-side chai and mocha.  The poster is asking about **browser-side** mocha and chai.

Comment: That's not the same issue. The `setTimeout` function used as example in this question doesn't have any error in its callback.

Answer (score 1):

I've published a package that resolves this issue.

First install the `check-chai` package:

`npm install --save check-chai`

Then in your tests, use `chai.use(checkChai);` and then use the `chai.check` helper function as shown below:

```
var chai = require('chai');
var dirtyChai = require('dirty-chai');
var checkChai = require('check-chai');
var expect = chai.expect;
chai.use(dirtyChai);
chai.use(checkChai);

describe('test', function() {

  it('should do something', function(done) {

    // imagine you have some API call here
    // and it returns (err, res, body)
    var err = null;
    var res = {};
    var body = {};

    chai.check(done, function() {
      expect(err).to.be.a('null');
      expect(res).to.be.an('object');
      expect(body).to.be.an('object');
    });

  });

});
```

Per [Is there a way to get Chai working with asynchronous Mocha tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235815/is-there-a-way-to-get-chai-working-with-asynchronous-mocha-tests/15208067#comment55687475_15208067) I published this as an NPM package.

Please see https://github.com/niftylettuce/check-chai for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Try chaiAsPromised! Aside from being excellently named, you can use statements like:

`expect(asyncToResultingValue()).to.eventually.equal(true)`

[Can confirm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ff6Ce.gif), works very well for Mocha + Chai.

https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised

Answer (score 1):

Very much related to and inspired by [Jean Vincent's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15208067/8985), we employ a helper function similar to his `check` function, but we call it `eventually` instead (this helps it match up with the naming conventions of chai-as-promised). It returns a function that takes any number of arguments and passes them to the original callback. This helps eliminate an extra nested function block in your tests and allows you to handle any type of async callback. Here it is written in ES2015:

```
function eventually(done, fn) {
  return (...args) => {
    try {
      fn(...args);
      done();
    } catch (err) {
      done(err);
    }
  };
};
```

Example Usage:

```
describe("my async test", function() {
  it("should fail", function(done) {
    setTimeout(eventually(done, (param1, param2) => {
      assert.equal(param1, "foo");   // this should pass
      assert.equal(param2, "bogus"); // this should fail
    }), 100, "foo", "bar");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I know there are many repeat answers and suggested packages to solve this however I haven't seen the simple solutions above offer a concise pattern for the two use cases. I am posting this as a consolidated answer for other who wish to copy-pasta:

### event callbacks

```
function expectEventCallback(done, fn) {
  return function() {
    try { fn(...arguments); }
    catch(error) { return done(error); }
    done();
  };
}
```

### node style callbacks

```
function expectNodeCallback(done, fn) {
  return function(err, ...args) {
    if (err) { return done(err); }
    try { fn(...args); }
    catch(error) { return done(error); }
    done();
  };
}
```

### example usage

```
it('handles event callbacks', function(done) {
  something.on('event', expectEventCallback(done, (payload) => {
    expect(payload).to.have.propertry('foo');
  }));
});

it('handles node callbacks', function(done) {
  doSomething(expectNodeCallback(done, (payload) => {
    expect(payload).to.have.propertry('foo');
  }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it extracting `try/catch` to a function.

```
function asyncExpect(test, done){
    try{
        test();
        done();
    } catch(error){
        done(error);
    }
}
```

Then in `it()` I call:

```
it('shall update a host', function (done) {
            testee.insertHost({_id: 'host_id'})
                .then(response => {
                    asyncExpect(() => {
                        expect(response).to.have.property('ok', 1);
                        expect(response).to.have.property('nModified', 1);
                    }, done);
                });

        });
```

It's also debugable.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this link provided by @richardforrester http://staxmanade.com/2015/11/testing-asyncronous-code-with-mochajs-and-es7-async-await/, describe can use a returned Promise if you omit the done parameter.

Only downside there has to be a Promise there, not any async function (you can wrap it with a Promise, thou). But in this case, code can be extremely reduced.

It takes into account failings from either in the initial funcThatReturnsAPromise function or the expectations:

```
it('should test Promises', function () { // <= done removed
    return testee.funcThatReturnsAPromise({'name': 'value'}) // <= return added
        .then(response => expect(response).to.have.property('ok', 1));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Timers during tests and async sounds pretty rough. There is a way to do this with a promise based approach.

```
const sendFormResp = async (obj) => {
    const result = await web.chat.postMessage({
        text: 'Hello world!',
    });
   return result
}
```

This async function uses a Web client (in this case it is Slacks SDK). The SDK takes care of the asynchronous nature of the API call and returns a payload. We can then test the payload within chai by running `expect` against the object returned in the async promise.

```
describe("Slack Logic For Working Demo Environment", function (done) {
    it("Should return an object", () => {
        return sdkLogic.sendFormResp(testModels.workingModel).then(res => {
            expect(res).to.be.a("Object");
        })
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach would be using [wait-for-expect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wait-for-expect) library.

```js
const waitForExpect = require("wait-for-expect")

test("it waits for the number to change", async () => {
  let numberToChange = 10;

  setTimeout(() => {
    numberToChange = 100;
  }, randomTimeout);

  await waitForExpect(() => {
    expect(numberToChange).toEqual(100);
  });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

What worked very well for me icm Mocha / Chai was the fakeTimer from Sinon's Library.
Just advance the timer in the test where necessary.

```
var sinon = require('sinon');
clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
// Do whatever. 
clock.tick( 30000 ); // Advances the JS clock 30 seconds.
```

Has the added bonus of having the test complete quicker.

Comment: I've definitely found myself mostly using solutions like this now when testing async code. It's good to have "done" callback Mocha (as shown in Jean Vincent's answer above) but tests are usually easier to write when you don't use it.

Answer (score -2):

You can also use domain module. For example:

```
var domain = require('domain').create();

domain.run(function()
{
    // place you code here
});

domain.on('error',function(error){
    // do something with error or simply print it
});
```