# How to test does function emits event after some time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, bdd, chai

I want to test in Chai does some event was emitted after some time.
My class :

```
export default class GeneratorService {
  constructor() {
      this.evn = new Events();
      this.generate();
  }

  generate() {
      this.check();
  }

  check() {
      setTimeout(() => {
            this.evn.events.emit('done', 'value');
      }, 2000);
  }
```

}

I have no idea how can I test does event `done` was emitted after 2s.

Comment: Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235815/is-there-a-way-to-get-chai-working-with-asynchronous-mocha-tests

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get Chai working with asynchronous Mocha tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235815/is-there-a-way-to-get-chai-working-with-asynchronous-mocha-tests)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By passing *one* argument to `it` (usually called `done`) and
then calling that argument when you want to finish your test.

This way you are signalling Mocha that this is an [async test](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code), and you want to wait until you call `done()` to finish the test, which you will do in an event listener for the "done" event from your `GeneratorService` instance.

Here's an example:

```
const chai = require('chai')
const EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter

chai.should()

class Client {
  constructor() {
    this.evt = new EventEmitter()
  }

  fireDone() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.evt.emit('done')
    }, 2000)
  }
}

describe('Client', function () {
  // increase mocha's default timeout to 3000ms, otherwise
  // the test will timeout after 2000ms.
  this.timeout(3000)

  const client = new Client()

  it('emits done after 2000 ms', function(done) {
    const now = Date.now()

    client.evt.on('done', function end(value) {
      (Date.now() - now).should.be.at.least(2000)
      // Do more assertions here; perhaps add tests for `value`.          

      // Here we call done, signalling to mocha
      // that this test is finally over.
      done()

      // remove listener so it doesn't re-fire on next test.
      client.evt.removeListener('done', end)
    })

    client.fireDone()
  })
})
```

*Note*: I replaced `GeneratorService` with `Client` and made it more compact for brevity.

Also, you can probably use Mocha's default 2000ms timeout limit to check that the event is indeed fired within 2 seconds, which negates the need to add the time comparison I check I've added in my example: `(Date.now() - now).should.be.at.least(2000)`.

Comment: Thanks. It's my 1st mocha/chai project, idk yet who's problem it is. 
Why you pass `err` to `done()`? It's giving me error bcz `err` is `undefined` = `Error: done() invoked with non-Error: value`.

Comment: Revised; You should call `done(err)` with the `err` argument being of type `Error` in case you want to signal to mocha that you want to end this test with an error (it failed). Otherwise just `done()`.